# Fetching json data in react shows TypeError

Tags: json, reactjs

I have some problem with fetching json data in my quiz app.

I have stored the json file in the same directory as App.js and Running.js

I want to show questions and the options for a correct answer.
All of it is stored in quiz.json file.

Running.js file:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {Collection,CollectionItem} from 'react-materialize';

class Running extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={ques:1,score:0,isLoaded:false,items:[]};
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("quiz.json")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result.conversations
          });
        },
        // Note: it's important to handle errors here
        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }
  render(){
    console.log(this.state.items);
   if(this.state.isLoaded){
    return (
            <div>
            <h1 class="header center teal-text text-lighten-2">React Quiz</h1>
             <br />
             <Collection header={this.state.items[0]["question"]} >
             {
              this.state.items[0]["answers"].map(ans =>(<CollectionItem href='#'>{ans.value}</CollectionItem>))
             } 
            </Collection>
            </div>
          )
   }
   else{
    return <div>Not Rendered</div>
   }

  }
}

export default Running;
```

The error message looks like this

```
TypeError: this.state.items is undefined
render
src/Running.js:37

  34 | <div>
  35 | <h1 class="header center teal-text text-lighten-2">React Quiz</h1>
  36 |  <br />
> 37 |  <Collection header={this.state.items[0]["question"]} >
  38 |  {
  39 |   this.state.items[0]["answers"].map(ans =>(<CollectionItem href='#'>{ans.value}</CollectionItem>))
  40 |  }
```

the json file looks like this :

```
[
  {
    "question": "How can you access the state of a component from inside of a member function?",
    "no": 1,
    "answers": [
      {
        "key": 1,
        "value": "this.getState()"
      },
      {
        "key": 2,
        "value": "this.prototype.stateValue"
      },
      {
        "key": 3,
        "value": "this.state"
      },
      {
        "key": 4,
        "value": "this.values"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "question": "Inline styling in React can be done as:",
    "no": 2,
    "answers": [
      {
        "key": 1,
        "value": "style:{{}}"
      },
      {
        "key": 2,
        "value": "style:{}"
      },
      {
        "key": 3,
        "value": "style:''"
      },
      {
        "key": 4,
        "value": "All"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "question": "For classless component we use?",
    "no": 3,
    "answers": [
      {
        "key": 1,
        "value": "functions"
      },
      {
        "key": 2,
        "value": "classes"
      },
      {
        "key": 3,
        "value": "JSX"
      },
      {
        "key": 4,
        "value": "None"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: make sure `result.conversations` is not undefined. Also in error callback you are setting `isLoaded` to `true` which I think should be false in this scenario.

Comment: thankyou i made the changes - isLoaded to false and then hosted the json data online. The problem must be in fetching it from the local directories. I couldn't solve that.

Comment: now you get it after hosting?

Comment: yes...the problem must be in fetching it from the directory.I cant figure it out. As i said above the json file is in src/ where App.js and Running.js are.